# Life after death

Tags: atma, death, afterlife

My question is related to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1978/3499) , As a Hindu I also believe in life after 
death and  rebirth. My question is where will be our soul in between death and  rebirth. Does it stay with the last life? I am asking because a sage said me about an unnatural death of a girl. Her father's death was also some thing unnatural. The sage said like she and her father soul is not standing together and they are so powerful to do some karma . Is it true?

Edited

1. What happens at Devaloka or Swarg?

Comment: To OP 1. The new edited questions are unrelated to the existing question. That makes the question too broad. 2. The questions are already addressed in this post : [What happens after death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1975/5212) which also makes the question a partial duplicate. 3. You should ask a new question if you have new questions. You should not add unrelated questions through edits after the answer is accepted. @K.C.Polai. You shouldn't add your new questions to existing questions. You should ask new questions instead. Search before asking new questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fate of the spirit after the death of the body highly depends on the Individual spirit/soul.

Broadly speaking, there are four possibilities:

1. The soul may go to devaloka/swargaloka or towards the realm of ishta devata, if a person has practiced dharma and devotion through out his life.
2. The soul may go to pitr loka or realms of manes, if a person has performed dharma, but not much of devotion. If one has practiced dharma and proper death rituals are performed, then high chances that such a person will go to pitr loka.
3. Those who have committed adharma and harmed many people, will either go to various narakas/hells and then take rebirth into lower creatures like animals or plants to undergo suffering.
4. At times, when death happens unnaturally or in a sudden improper manner, for example, death through choking, or through accidents or due to black magic etc. especially in cases of painful deaths, the souls may get stuck in earthly realm itself as a spirit.

Well, practice of dharma leads one to higher realms, practice of adharma leads to suffering. That is the broad rule that governs birth, death and rebirth.

In Manu Smriti, Bhagavad Purana, or Garuda Purana you will get more details. Even upanishads speak about devayana and pitryana.